# How do I change one font to another in Safari?

Tags: safari

Lets say I have a website with Trebuchet MS. How do I change all instances of that font into something more appealing, like Lucida Grande?

Comment: I think you need a custom style sheet, there is some info at  https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/AddingStyles/AddingStyles.html

Comment: You are developing something with Safari Extensions or just want to view it in the browser ?